# py.test multiple tests for different results

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

Is there a good way to do this.

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[
    "web01-east.domain.com",
    "web01-master-east.domain.com",
    "web01.domain.com",
])
def patch_socket(request, monkeypatch):
    def gethostname():
        return request.param

    monkeypatch.setattr(socket, 'gethostname', gethostname)


def test__get_pod(patch_socket):
    assert __get_pod() == 'east'
```

Right now that'll work but I want to have the last test fail but be ok since if there is no -east in the hostname the __get_pod() function returns unknown.

Is there a way to tell py.test that I want to pass in a param list of what tests should equal like

```
[
 ('web01-east.domain.com', 'web')
 ('redis01-master-east.domain.com', 'redis-master')
 ('web01.domain.com', 'Unknown')
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of monkey-patching `socket.gethostname`, make the `__get_pod` to accept a parameter. It will make the code more testable:

Here's an example with [`pytest.mark.parametrize`](http://pytest.org/latest/parametrize.html#pytest-mark-parametrize-parametrizing-test-functions):

```
import re

import pytest


def __get_pod(hostname):  # dummy impl.
    hostname = hostname.split('.', 1)[0]
    if '-' not in hostname:
        return 'Unknown'
    hostname = re.sub(r'\d+', '', hostname)
    return hostname.rsplit('-', 1)[0]


@pytest.mark.parametrize(['hostname', 'expected'], [
    ["web01-east.domain.com", 'web'],
    ["redis01-master-east.domain.com", 'redis-master'],
    ["web01.domain.com", 'Unknown'],
])
def test__get_pod(hostname, expected):
    assert __get_pod(hostname) == expected
```

If you want to do it with mockey-patching (or, you can't change `__get_pod` signature)

```
import re
import socket

import pytest


def __get_pod():
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    hostname = hostname.split('.', 1)[0]
    if '-' not in hostname:
        return 'Unknown'
    hostname = re.sub(r'\d+', '', hostname)
    return hostname.rsplit('-', 1)[0]


@pytest.mark.parametrize(['hostname', 'expected'], [
    ["web01-east.domain.com", 'web'],
    ["redis01-master-east.domain.com", 'redis-master'],
    ["web01.domain.com", 'Unknown'],
])
def test__get_pod(monkeypatch, hostname, expected):
    monkeypatch.setattr(socket, 'gethostname', lambda: hostname)
    assert __get_pod() == expected
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to falsetru's answer, which is more like what you've started like is to use the return value from the fixture. Given that `__get_pod` looks something like (modified from falsetru's dummy):

```
def __get_pod():
    hostname = socket.gethostname().split('.', 1)[0]
    if '-' not in hostname:
        return 'Unknown'
    hostname = re.sub(r'\d+', '', hostname)
    return hostname.rsplit('-', 1)[0]
```

You can test it like:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[
    ('web01-east.domain.com', 'web'),
    ('redis01-master-east.domain.com', 'redis-master'),
    ('web01.domain.com', 'Unknown')
])
def patch_socket(request, monkeypatch):
    def gethostname():
        return request.param[0]

    monkeypatch.setattr(socket, 'gethostname', gethostname)
    return request.param[1]

def test__get_pod(patch_socket):
    assert __get_pod() == patch_socket
```

This requires the less changes from your original code.